# Theme.AppCompat.Light actionbaractivity vs activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

If I want to use `Theme.AppCompat.Light` and target minSDK 15, do I have to use ActionBarActivity or can I use Activity if I want to have the Action Bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

To use AppCompat you have to:

- All of your Activities must extend from **AppCompatActivity**, which
  extends from FragmentActivity from the v4 support library, so you can
  continue to use fragments.
- All of your themes (that want an Action Bar/Toolbar) must inherit
  from Theme.AppCompat. There are variants available, including Light
  and NoActionBar.

More info here:
http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html